# SELECT MAX keeps converting DATETIME to VARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, max, varchar

Trying to write something that produces the MAX date for a record and then show all records that have a MAX date less than today, but the SQL query keeps converting the DATETIME field to a VARCHAR so I'm unable to use `maxdate < GetDate()`

The code I'm trying to use is 
`'Max Day'=(SELECT MAX (del.original_stop) FROM del, line WHERE del.obj_id=T2.obj_id AND del.type=0 AND line.opt <> 1)`

T2.obj_id is defined in a LEFT OUTER JOIN in my main FROM clause.

Any ideas?

*Updating w/full query

```
SELECT
T1.doc AS "Document",
T1.owner AS "Own",
T1.last_up AS "Last Updated (EST)",

"Dollars"=ISNULL((SELECT CAST(SUM(fund_amt) AS DECIMAL(16,2)) FROM c_fund T3 WHERE T2.obj_id=T3.obj_id),0),
"Max Day"=(SELECT MAX(del.orig_stop) FROM del, line WHERE del.obj_id=T2.obj_id AND del.del_type=0 AND line.opt <> 1)

FROM
dsk T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN doc_object T2 ON T1.obj_id=T2.obj_id

WHERE
T1.icon_id=4
AND
T1.last_up >= '2018/01/21' AND T1.last_up <= '2018/01/24'

ORDER BY
"Last Updated (EST)" desc
```

And I know about the commas in the FROM clause, will fix those shortly.

Comment: When you added the SQL tag, a large box popped up and suggested that you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as features and syntax between them vary. Why did you ignore that suggestion? Now we have to go through the **What DBMS are you using? Features and support vary between them, and knowing which one you're using is relevant. Please add a tag for the DBMS so we don't waste your time or ours answering only to find out it won't work on your specific database.** nonsense, and you don't get answers for a while until you do so.

Comment: Try using CONVERT() function 

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `as` to assign aliases:

```
select (SELECT MAX(del.original_stop)
        FROM del JOIN
             line 
             ON del.obj_id=T2.obj_id AND del.type=0 AND line.opt <> 1
       ) as max_day,
       . . .
```

Also, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

If `original_stop` is a string, then my first advice is to fix the data.  You should be storing dates and times in native formats, not as strings.

If for some reason you cannot fix the data model, then you can use `convert()` .  You'll need to [peruse](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx) the formats available for the function.

Comment: I just updated the OP with the full query. I tried your suggestion and I'm still having issues with it converting a DATETIME field from the DB into a VARCHAR in the results.